# Why do my image filters cause a crash only after selecting an image from the gallery?

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, illegalstateexception, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to create image filters in my app, but they only work if I take the image with the camera on my actual device. If I try using the code on an emulator, using the camera still breaks it. If I select an image from the phone's gallery, it crashes. I'm getting InvocationTargetException and IllegalStateException when I run this code.

```
Bitmap darken(Bitmap bmp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bmp.getHeight(); j++) {
            int red = (bmp.getPixel(i, j) >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int green = (bmp.getPixel(i, j) >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int blue = (bmp.getPixel(i, j) >> 0) & 0xFF;
            red -= 25.5;
            green -= 25.5;
            blue -= 25.5;
            if (red < 0) {
                red = 0;
            }
            if (green < 0) {
                green = 0;
            }
            if (blue < 0) {
                blue = 0;
            }
            bmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Here's where that method gets called.

```
final Button darkenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.darkenButton);
darkenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BitmapDrawable bDraw = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bmap = bDraw.getBitmap();
            bmap = darken(bmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmap);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are getting IllegalStateException because your imageView is not having any drawable when you are fetching it, before fetching the drawable make sure that you have some image in your imageView.

Comment: @Ashwani I'm getting the illegal state exception when I'm running the darken method. The imageView updates to the selected image, at least in the gui, but actually filtering the image causes it to crash inside the inner for loop the first time it runs.